# Induction technique on the fibonacci sequence

Tags: proof-verification

> \begin{equation}
> F_n=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}
> \end{equation}

Proof: Let n=1 thus,
\begin{align*}
F_1&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{{\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
Suppose
\begin{equation}
F_k=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{equation}
Also $F(k+1)=F(k)+F(k-1)$
\begin{align*}
F(k)+F(k-1)&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}+(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})+1)(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})+1)(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}))(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}))(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k+1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k+1}}{\sqrt{5}}\hfill 
\end{align*}

I was told there was a mistake but I feel this is right can I get clarification on my proof if it seems right?

Comment: ok sorry I'll post my solution there but my proof looks different then the solutions given on there

Comment: You should have two bases cases $F_1$ and $F_2$ for the inductive step to work on.

Comment: I don't follow this is a new technique for me. I was told base case show it for 1 which I did. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It is explained in the duplicate, see the answer by hypergeometric.

Comment: In your initial case you only proved $F_1$. In your inductive step you find $F_{k+1}$ using both $F_k$ and $F_{k-1}$. If we use the inductive step to prove $F_3$ it relies upon both $F_2$ and $F_1$ being true but you haven't established that $F_2$ is true.

Comment: Oh ok I see now but my logic in the main block is ok if I add the base case for 2 also? That will be straight forward to add at least.

Comment: Your algebra for the inductive step looks ok to me. Did your teacher/instructor give any detail of what was wrong with it?

Comment: No I bet it was the base case two though which now makes sense to me.

Comment: Also instead of doing $F_2$ you could do $F_0$ which is slightly easier arithmetically. Then $F_2$ is done inductively from $F_1$ and $F_0$.